# Why doesn't my code detect any variable which I input into this list when using .index(), when it is in the list?

Tags: python, list, valueerror

```
wordList = []
counter = 0
y = 1
total = 0
wordTotal = 0
while y == 1:
    word = input("enter words\n")
    continued = input("do you want to continue? y or n ")
    if continued == "n":
        y = 0
    total = total + 1
    newWords = []
    wordList.append(word)
    wordCount = wordList.count(word)
    totals = []
    if wordCount > 1:
        wordTotal = wordTotal - 1
        whichWord = newWords.index(word)
        totals[whichWord] = totals[whichWord] + 1
    if wordCount == 1:
        wordTotal = total - wordTotal
        newWords.append(word)
        print(newWords)
        totals.append(1)
        print(totals)
    if wordTotal == 0:
        wordTotal = 1

print("the number of different words is", wordTotal)
```

This program takes user inputted words, and counts how many repetitions of certain words there are, and how many unqiue words there are. In the second if statement in my code, when I try to index through the array newWords[], and update the value of a repeated word from 1->2, 2->3 etc.., it says ValueError: '...' is not in list. However, when i print the newWords list out in the third if statement, the value is there.

So sorry if I have made an obivous mistake - I am relatively new to python, all help is hugely appreciated :D.

Comment: I strongly recommend that you research use of the *in* operator and *set* functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Python 3.8+ you can use the following code.

The loop can be controlled based on the user input. If user just presses RETURN then the value returned by *input()* will be an empty string which is 'falsy'. Otherwise add the word to a dictionary and increment the word count as required.

Therefore, all you need is:

```
counter = {}

while (word := input('Enter a word or <return> to end: ')):
    counter[word] = counter.get(word, 0) + 1

print(*counter.items())
```

Comment: Only thing is, this exercise wants me to display the number of times each word has shown up, not just the total number of unique/non-unique words - sorry if that wasn't clear from my inital post D:

Comment: @kei Answer edited now that you've clarified the problem

Comment: You can simplify it even further using [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) which is the builtin type made for this kind of thing.

Comment: @Jasmijn Counter is very useful but the additional import isn't justified for this trivial case

Comment: @Vlad I think it's important that people know what's in the standard library, even if they make a different choice of datastructure in the end, that's why I suggested it in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

The first time you enter inside this if

```
if wordCount > 1:
        wordTotal = wordTotal - 1
        whichWord = newWords.index(word)
        totals[whichWord] = totals[whichWord] + 1
```

word is equal to the 2nd word entered by the user, you agree?
but since the only time you're adding a word inside newWords is in these lines :

```
if wordCount == 1:
        wordTotal = total - wordTotal
        newWords.append(word)
        print(newWords)
        totals.append(1)
```

when you get to the `if wordCount > 1:` above, the only word inside newWords is the first word the user did input, therefore the 2nd word isn't in it, and ence why your error

Let's do a run together :
Users input for instance "hello", so hello is inside word, you add it to

```
wordList.append(word)
```

and wordcounts = 1, so you go inside the if loop

```
if wordCount == 1:
            wordTotal = total - wordTotal
            newWords.append(word)
            print(newWords)
            totals.append(1)
```

now newWords = ["Hello"]

Now users input another word, for instance "World"
so now

word = "World"
wordCounts = 2

but

```
  newWords = ["Hello"]
```

because you never added "World" to it
but in

```
if wordCount > 1:
            wordTotal = wordTotal - 1
            whichWord = newWords.index(word)
            totals[whichWord] = totals[whichWord] + 1
```

you're trying to access the word "World" inside newWords